# Difference Between Many to many , and Many to one in both tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, uml

I have 2 classes , Class A and Class B and I have a Many to Many relationship between them,
I want to know the difference between :

- Making Many to Many annotation in both classes and the Hibernate will generate automatically the third class (let's name it Class C).
  And ...
- Making Many to One annotation in both classes and create manually the third class, Class C , with migration of 2 IDs of Classes A and B annotated with One to Many.

It will affected my UML class Diagramme ?

Comment: What is "the Hibernate"?

Comment: @qwerty_so I think it’s https://hibernate.org

Comment: @Christophe Maybe. Or maybe not. If people ask here they shall ask proper questions which themselves should not be questionable. Can't be too hard to fix that.

Comment: @qwerty_so I think OP put a hibernate and a jpa tag, which sets the context pretty well and makes it a proper hibernate question as much as an UML question

Comment: @Christophe I'm less the expert in that area than you ;-) Maybe jpa is enough. But if someone appoaches me with a UML question he needs to talk a bit more UML rather than coding. I know that most coders are just about "that UML" - just a burden. Well then, can't be helped. Pun intended.

Answer (score 0):

### Implementing many-to-many associations

A binary many-to-many association has two ends.  A key question is in which direction you want to be able to navigate:

- if you only want to navigate from `A` to `B`,  you could implement the association by storing in each instance of `A` a collection of references to its related `B` instances.  We say that A owns the B association-end.  It's many-to-many, since nothing prevents a same instance of `B` to be referred to several times and in different instances of `A`.
- If you want to navigate bidriectionally, i.e. from `A` to `B` and from `B` to `A`.  You could duplicate this mechanism and also store in every `B` instance a collection of references to its related `A` instances. You'd need a little more to ensure consistency between those two collections.
- Whether bidrectionally or unidirectionally,  you could also outsource the association.  This is frequently done when the many-to-many associations that are association-classes (i.e the link between two entities is enriched with additional properties).

By the way this last implementation option is very similar to the implementation that would result from a model that would introduce an intermediary class C with many to one relations to A and B. ( "similar" but not "equivalent", since UML allows duplicates links in many-to-many associations)

### Many-to-many and ORM

In the context of an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) such as [hibernate](https://hibernate.org/), this last approach is a popular mapping strategy, even without association-classes. To simplify:

- The `A` class would be mapped to a `TA` table, `B` to a `TB` table, and the many-to many association to a `TA_B` table, also called the "*join-table*" (in hibernate-speak, or more generally an association table in common language).
- This association table holds a pair of ids for each link between an instance of `A` and an instance of `B`. The relational schema allows to use this table to efficiently navigate bidirectionally. So if you have any `A`, a simple query gives you all the related `B`s, and conversely, and in addition both sides are mechanically kept in sync since it's the same row of the same table.

However, if an entity does not know anything about the association, it cannot find the elements and the rules to navigate in the other direction.  So it's all a question about what the ORM layer can find out and what dependencies you are ready to accept.

### Conclusion: The Hibernate case

I'm not an hibernate expert,  but based on my knowledge of ORM and the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html), it appears that the `@ManyToMany` annotation:

- can be used only on one side of the association, but resulting in a unidirectional navigation from this side only (see [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html), in particular section "*2.2.5.3.2.2. Default values*", the first example).
- should be used on the two sides of the association for enabling a bi-directional navigation (see for example, section "*2.2.5.3.2.1. Definition*").

If you create yourself a class C with many-to-one associations, you are using a slightly different model, which addressed the same needs.